# @Html.ActionLink not working in MVC when jquery used in another page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I am working on a MVC web application. As one of my webpages (Say PageX) was not working without disabling `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` in `_Layout.cshtml` and enabling in PageX.

When `PageX` is loaded, runs `jquery` and loads data, the tabs from `_Layout.shtml` that has `@Html.ActionLink()` does not work. It is working only during initial page load.

What should I do to make it work?

---

In `PageX`, following script runs when loads `datatable`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li[data-toggle="tab"]').on( 'shown.table1.tab', function (e) {
                    $.fn.dataTable.tables( {visible: true, api: true} ).columns.adjust();
});

var t = $('#example').removeAttr('width').DataTable({
     code here
        }).draw();
});
```

The tabs that are part of `PageX` still work after loading data. Only tabs from `_Layout.shtml` does not work

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink()` has nothing to do with jquery. But if you have scripts associated with it (e.g. for your tabs plugin), then you need to show you code.

Comment: I saw a similar bug:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673821/how-can-i-preventdefault-on-html-actionlink

Comment: What do you mean a bug. `ActionLink()` just creates an `<a>` tag. If something is not working for you its a bug in **your** code.

Answer (score 0):

I had $("li").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); } in my PageX that was interfering the one in _layout.cshtml .

Following the link: [How can I preventDefault on HTML.ActionLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673821/how-can-i-preventdefault-on-html-actionlink)
solved the issue.